# Как из списка точек получить два списка координат?

Tags: haskell

Имея набор точек `X`, `Y` на новых линиях строки, как короче всего получить два списка `X` и `Y` отдельно? Или, что то же - имея 1 список, как получить два списка с элементами на чётных и нечётных позициях?

```hs
"1 2\n3 4\n" -> [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Из 1 инпута можно получить второй через `words`. Для второго инпута можно сделать

```hs
splitOnPos [] = [[], []]
splitOnPos (x1:x2:xs) = [x1:odds, x2:evens]  
    where [odds, evens] = splitOnPos xs
```

Но может можно как-то короче сделать для первого? Или укоротить решение для второго? Может быть как-то можно одновременно применить `head` и `last` после `map words . lines`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```hs
ghci> import Data.List (transpose)
ghci> transpose . map words . lines $ "1 2\n3 4\n"
[["1","3"],["2","4"]]
```

Правда тут на выходе список строк, как и в вашем варианте

```hs
ghci> zipWith ($) [map head, map last] . repeat . map words . lines $ "1 2\n3 4\n"
[["1","3"],["2","4"]]
```

так что

```
ghci> transpose . map (map read . words) . lines $ "1 2\n3 4\n" :: [[Int]]
[[1,3],[2,4]]
```

Ну и если дальше развивать ваш вариант

```hs
ghci> mapM map [head, last] . map words . lines $ "1 2\n3 4\n"
[["1","3"],["2","4"]]
ghci> mapM (map . (read .)) [head, last] . map words . lines $ "1 2\n3 4\n" :: [[Int]]
[[1,3],[2,4]]
```

для второго примера

```hs
ghci> import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
ghci> transpose . chunksOf 2 $ [1, 2, 3, 4]
[[1,3],[2,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант есть:

```hs
zipWith ($) [map head, map last] . repeat . map words . lines
```